# Rotation of a random uniform vector over a diamond region

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

Consider de region $\mathcal{C}_1$(shaded region below)

[image]

Consider a random uniformly distributed vector $U$ over $\mathcal{C}_1$. I know that
the density function of $U$ is

$$
f_{U}=\left\{\begin{array}{lr}
\dfrac{1}{4}, & \text { if }U \in \mathcal{C}_1 \\[1em]
0, & \text { otherwise }
\end{array}\right.=\frac{1}{4} \mathbf{1}_{\{U \in \mathcal{C}_1\}}.
$$

with marginals

$$
f_{U_1}= \frac{1-x}{2},\quad f_{u_2}=\frac{1-y}{2}
$$

Let $\mathbf{r}$ be the rotation angle function where the angle is $\dfrac{\pi}{4}$.
Then, for every point $(x,y)$ in $\mathcal{C}_1$ we can obtain the rotated coordinates using the rotation matrix and since $\sin \left(\dfrac{\pi}{4}\right)=\cos \left(\dfrac{\pi}{4}\right)=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ then

$$
\left[\begin{array}{l}
x' \\
y'
\end{array}\right]=
\left[\begin{array}{cc}
\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\
-\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{l}
x \\
y
\end{array}\right].
$$

$$
\mathbf{r}(x,y)=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(x+y,y-x).
$$

Now, let $V=\mathbf{r}(U)$ the transformation of $U$ under $\mathbf{r}$. How can I find the density marginals $V_1$ and $V_2$. And how can I show V is a product measure?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The resulting density is $\mathbb{U}(x)_{(-1,1)} \times \mathbb{U}(y)_{(-1,1)} $ without any computation.

Comment: So the marginals would be $V_1=\mathbf{r}(U(x)_{(-1,1)})$ and $V_2=\mathbf{r}(U(y)_{(-1,1)})$ ?

Comment: Yes, with $r=1/2$

Comment: To prove V is a product measure, do I need to check first that $V_1$ and $V_2$ are measures on $(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{B})$ so their product $V=V_1\times V_2$ is a product measure?